# Commit update log file to main db file

Tags: asp.net-core, litedb

I have a question about LiteDB. I make an asp.net mvc application to interact with LiteDB. But all data change only save in log.db file. How can I update to main db file?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you send the source code, please?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following Statement:

**multiple operations against LiteDB**

```
db.Commit();
```

Comment: Thank you! But It's not affected. I don't use transaction when insert.

Comment: can you share script, i can help ur problem

Comment: Thanks you Mr @Uday.  I have solve my problem. I receive a answer for this. While auto-checkpoint is supposed to run eventually (by default, every time the log file reaches 8MB), it might not happen if your application is always using the datafile.

Try running a db.Checkpoint() every once in a while.